# Domain generalization for Random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, transfer-learning

I have recently been thinking about domain generalization. It is well known that domain generalization aims to learn a model from one or several different but related domains that will generalize well on unseen testing domains.
And as for the Random forest model, By Breiman ([Random forest](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/randomforest2001.pdf), 2001), the generalization bound of random forest is related to the strength of every single classifier tree and the correlation between trees in forests.

[image]

Therefore, the problem for random forest domain generalization is transferred to decrease the correlation between trees and preserve the strength of every tree. I know random forest uses the Bagging method itself to ensure low variation and good generalization performance.

My question is, is it possible to directly delete trees with high correlation values to decrease the correlation and make the random forest more general?

I think maybe it is because if we delete those trees, it will also affect the bias accuracy of the model they get. That's because the random forest uses voting to get the final results. Is it true, or have any other reasons? BTW, I think the strength and correlation of random forest is not independent. The more strength of a sigle classifier, less correlation in random forest. Is it true?

Comment: The trees are correlated because they predict the same thing, so they agree when they are "convinced" that the result is true. For completely uncorrelated trees, they would need to be completely random. In this sense, with completely random trees, you would have a perfectly generalizable model, but with the worst achievable performance on any domain (random predictions).

Comment: @Tim, thanks for your comment. I totally agree with your opinion. So for the random forest generalization problem, we need to do a trade-off between the good performance of the model (with high correlation maybe) and poor performance (with low correlation). And I think this is a general trade-off problem for all ML models; bias, and variation. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. You could start cherry-picking the most correlated trees for reducing variance, or the most uncorrelated trees for reducing bias, but both approaches would be equally arbitrary and contrary to the general approach used in the random forest - bootstrap averaging and randomizing it.